# No parameterless constructor defined for this object when simply copying site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express

I'm getting the above error.  All I have done is copied an existing site and set-up debugging to use a different port using IISExpress in Visual Studio.

Any ideas why I would suddenly get this error? Normally I get this error when StructureMap cannot for some reason resolve a dependency to inject into a controller. But this has me stumped.  The code-base is the same.  All I've done is copied the code into another folder!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a while to figure out.  Basically, uninstalling Mvc4 beta solved it.  There must have been some inferred reference to Mvc4 which was breaking the code.  The code-base was **exactly** the same yet the whole app broke.  The folder where the application still worked may have had some old reference to Mvc3 somehow which was preserved.